# IndexError: 'tuple index out of range' for Training set while doing SDG Softmax

Tags: python, pandas, softmax

Please help me understand where I might be going wrong in the following code because while calculating accuracy for the training data, the above IndexError: **Tuple index out of range** is constantly occurring.

- y has been converted to dummies so that there is a column for each class.
- SGD algorithm defined

My code:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

y = df["label"]
X = df.drop("label", axis=1)

y_dummies = pd.get_dummies(y)

X_train, X_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.25,random_state=25)

X_scaled = StandardScaler().fit_transform(X_train)

import numpy as np

def softmax(scores):
    scaled_scores = scores-scores.max(axis=1, keepdims=True) 
    exp_scores = np.exp(scaled_scores)
    softmax_scores = exp_scores/(np.sum(exp_scores,axis=1,keepdims=True))
    return softmax_scores

def get_log_loss(X, w, y):
    scores = np.dot(X,w)
    predictions = softmax(scores)
    log_likelihood = np.sum(y*np.log(predictions))/len(y)
    log_loss = -log_likelihood
    return log_loss

def get_gradient(X, w, y):
    scores = np.dot(X,w)
    predictions = softmax(scores)
    error = y - predictions

    gradient = -(np.dot(X.T, error))/len(y)
    return gradient

def SGD_softmax(X, y, lr, batch_size, max_epochs):
    w = np.zeros([X.shape[1], y.shape[1]]) 
    old_loss = 1000
    losses = [] 
    target = .01 
    
    count = 0
    while (count<max_epochs):
        shuffled_index = np.random.permutation(X.shape[0]) 
        batch_starts = range(0, X.shape[0], batch_size) 
        
        for start_index in batch_starts: 
            batch = shuffled_index[start_index:start_index + batch_size]
            x_batch = X[batch]
            y_batch = y[batch]
            gradient = get_gradient(x_batch, w, y_batch)
            w = w-lr*gradient
            
        current_loss = get_log_loss(X, w, y) 
        gain = (old_loss - current_loss)/np.abs(old_loss)
        losses.append(current_loss)
        old_loss = current_loss
        
       
        if (gain<target):
            lr = lr/2
            
        count = count+1
        
    return (w, losses)

const = np.ones((X_scaled.shape[0],1))
X_train_biased = np.concatenate([const,X_scaled],1)

max_epochs=15
batch_size = 32
lr=.01

w, losses = SGD_softmax(X_train_biased, y_train.values, lr, batch_size, max_epochs)
```

The error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-39-1be95351e661> in <module>()
     10 lr=.01
     11 
---> 12 w, losses = SGD_softmax(X_train_biased, y_train.values, lr, batch_size, max_epochs)
     13 predictions = np.argmax(np.dot(X_train_biased, w), axis=1)
     14 actual = np.argmax(y_train.values, axis=1)

<ipython-input-36-f0dfc421945b> in SGD_softmax(X, y, lr, batch_size, max_epochs)
     29 def SGD_softmax(X, y, lr, batch_size, max_epochs):
---> 30     w = np.zeros([X.shape[1], y.shape[1]]) 
     31     old_loss = 1000
     32     losses = []

IndexError: tuple index out of range
```